# Django forms edit instance - clean without testing instanced object

Tags: django, django-forms

The following code works for validating a new object. It will query all objects, and check if there's a conflict in the date interval. The problem is, that when I try to edit an existing instance of this object, it will fail because the start_date and end_date are already in the database (from the same object being edited).

```
class BoxRateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, building, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BoxRateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(building=building)

    class Meta:
        model = BoxRate
        exclude = ()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(BoxRateForm, self).clean()
        start_date = cleaned_data.get("start_date")
        end_date = cleaned_data.get("end_date")
        category = cleaned_data.get("category")
        boxrate_list = BoxRate.objects.filter(category=category)
        if not start_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Informar data inicial")
        if not end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Informar data final")
        if start_date > end_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Data inicial maior que data final.")
        for boxrate in boxrate_list:
            if boxrate.start_date <= start_date and start_date < boxrate.end_date and \
            boxrate.start_date < end_date and end_date <= boxrate.end_date:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Existe outra tarifa para esta categoria com a mesma data")
            elif start_date < boxrate.start_date and boxrate.end_date <= end_date:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Existe outra tarifa para esta categoria com a mesma data")
            elif start_date < boxrate.start_date and boxrate.start_date < end_date and end_date <= boxrate.end_date :
                raise forms.ValidationError("Existe outra tarifa para esta categoria com a mesma data")
            elif boxrate.start_date <= start_date and start_date < boxrate.end_date and boxrate.end_date < end_date :
                raise forms.ValidationError("Existe outra tarifa para esta categoria com a mesma data")
            elif boxrate.start_date == start_date and boxrate.end_date == end_date:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Existe outra tarifa para esta categoria com a mesma data")
            else:
                continue
        #return cleaned_data
```

I guess that if I can get the id of the object being edited, i could just skip the check in for loop.

such as:

```
for boxrate in boxrate_list:
    object_id = ???
    if boxrate.id != object_id:
        #run all date tests
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `self.instance` to refer to object being edited.

Comment: @Rohan, exactly what I was looking for! `self.instance.id` did the trick. Thank you!!! :)